# Exception: SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: java, apache-spark

Why does this code produces this exception? How can I avoid it

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("startingSpark").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    List<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> visitsRaw = new ArrayList<>();
    visitsRaw.add(new Tuple2<>(4, 18));
    visitsRaw.add(new Tuple2<>(6, 4));
    visitsRaw.add(new Tuple2<>(10, 9));

    List<Tuple2<Integer, String>> usersRaw = new ArrayList<>();
    usersRaw.add(new Tuple2<>(1, "John"));
    usersRaw.add(new Tuple2<>(2, "Bob"));
    usersRaw.add(new Tuple2<>(3, "Alan"));
    usersRaw.add(new Tuple2<>(4, "Doris"));
    usersRaw.add(new Tuple2<>(5, "Marybelle"));
    usersRaw.add(new Tuple2<>(6, "Raquel"));

    JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> visits = sc.parallelizePairs(visitsRaw);
    JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> users = sc.parallelizePairs(usersRaw);

    JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, String>> joinedRdd = visits.join(users);

    joinedRdd.foreach(System.out::println);
    sc.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clause 'System.out::println' is not serializable, can be changed to:

```
joinedRdd.foreach(v->System.out.println(v));
```

Or for print values on Driver node such construction can be used:

```
joinedRdd.collect().forEach(System.out::println);
```